# How do I capture a smart contract function return values when changing the contract status?

Tags: solidity, dapps

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.6;

contract Demo {

    uint a;

    function set(uint b) returns (uint) {
        a = b;
        return a * b;
    }

    function get() constant returns (uint) {
        return a;
    }
}
```

Q: The function "get()" is a constant function, it is not changed the contract status, it just return the "a" value, when the function "set(uint b)" called, it will return a transaction hash, and wait to the mined, so then, how to capture the return value "a * b" ?
Many blogs and answer say it can't captured, but use event can do this, But a online compiler can do this, https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity , and how the browser-solidity did it ? 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

These return values are not available to external clients in the case of a sendTransaction. The return value is the transaction hash which indicates a transaction was submitted for verification.

So, if they're not accessible, why have them?

Other contracts can read these values. External clients can read these values when they `.call()` functions in read-only ("dry run") mode. For example, it might be useful to confirm `return true;` using `contract.function.call()` and then send a transaction with `contract.function()`.

There are design patterns for coping with the unknown result. Leaving that out as it's straying off-topic.

Hope it helps.